# How can i access session value in class library?(System.Web.Current.Session is not working)

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I am developing an application architecture that uses 2 sub projects: a) asp.net web application (it covers user interface and business logic) and b) class library. (it covers data access layer)

After system user successfully logs in , the user information is stored in a session object.

The problem I am facing is when I try to access that session object in class library project(data access layer), it always returns null.

I need to access the session object in class library project because, in my case each user has their own username and password for database access(for security reasons);

Comment: How are you accessing session object? Kindly share some code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the current session from `System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["YourSession"]`

You might have to add a reference to `System.Web` in the class library.